# Como hacer una consulta especifica en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Quiero hacer una consulta en una base de datos la cual busque el nombre de un usaurio si existe su id en la coleccion, me explico

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee5"),
   user: '649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2',
   friend: [
            {
             id: '649dbc81ff38d4464e5c0edd',
             name: 'paco'
            },
           {
             id: '649dbc63ff38d4464e5c0ed8',
             name: 'angel'
           }
       ]
   }
```

Este es mi objeto ya en la base de datos, mi consulta en si es buscar si hay algún usuario con el nombre 'x' en el objeto `friend` del `user` seleccionado es decir, ejemplo, quiero saber si hay algún amigo llamado "paco" en la lista del usuario "649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2" y claro que me regrese la consulta mostrando eso

```
{
  id: '649dbc81ff38d4464e5c0edd',
  name: 'paco'
}
```

intente con esta consulta

```
db.friends.find(
                 {user:"649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2", friend: {"name":"paco"}}
)
```

pero en la consola no regresa nada, como que se buggea, soy nuevo en mongoDB, y aunque consultando referencias no entiendo bien como se haría la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes buscar por el ID del `user` y también por un elemento dentro de `friends` que cumpla con el nombre que buscas:

```
db.friends.find({user: "649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2", friend: { $elemMatch: {name:"paco"} }})
```

Pero esto te devolvería todo el documento, es decir si no lo tiene no te devuelve nada, pero si si lo tiene te devuelve el documento completo.

Otra opción podría ser buscar el usuario por su ID sin filtros, y una vez tengas el documento del usuario buscar dentro de sus amigos a "paco" usando algún filtro sobre el array (según el lenguaje de programación que estés usando)

Answer (score 1):

Mongo siempre te va a devolver la estructura desde el documento, pero puedes filtrar para obtener solo el sub-documento de tu interés estableciendo un segundo filtro y usando el selector $elemMatch, de esta forma:

```
db.q597823.find({user: "649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2"},{friend: {$elemMatch: {name: "paco"}}});
```

En mi caso, devuelve:

```javascript
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee5"),
    friend: [ { id: '649dbc81ff38d4464e5c0edd', name: 'paco' } ]
  }
]
```

Dejé el ejemplo en el [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/smOXWuF-JMw).